Using C#, how to filter Excel Worksheet records based on a column value
I am trying to filter an Excel worksheet using the following, where the variable sLastRoad = "STREET RD".
     Excel.Range filterRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;   
     filterRange.AutoFilter(5, sLastRoad);
     filterRange.Rows.Count //returns all 1121 rows.
type here

If i go to the Excel worksheet in Excel and apply a filter on column 5 for "STREET RD" there are 32 records shown.
This code is called repeatedly in a loop and each time it returns all the records in the Excel worksheet
Any guidance would be appreciated.
